GoogleSignInClient fails to authenticate secondary Gmail account in compose project
Could you please help me?
I have a project on compose where I authenticate via Firebase (Gmail option). I use GoogleSignInClient that.
When I sign in with my personal gmail account it works fine. But when I try to log in with another gmail account althought I get -1 (RESULT_OK) from ActivityResult I still cannot log in. The screen with email dissapears, it loads little bit and nothing happens.
After pressing Google button one more time the screen with emails try to appear and vanishes right away. Maybe anyone came across this problem?
fun handleActivityResult(result: ActivityResult) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("MyResultCode", result.resultCode.toString())
            _logInResultState.value = RequestResult.Loading
            val signInResult = gmailLogInUseCase.signIn(result)
            handleAuthResult(signInResult)
        }
    }
}

Full code is here:
https://pastebin.com/CkEpNjKC
